# How to remove styles of Masterpage iframe from childpage iframe when using _self?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, iframe, webforms

The `Master page` is written as an `ASP.NET Web Form`. It's an `iframe` with it's own styles and widgets that persist across the application. I am using `_self` to replace the current page with the child page.

The problem is that the child page reloads the master page along with it's styles when clicked. How do I remove those styles?

[image: Iframe in iframe]

Comment: Regarding `The problem is that the child page reloads the master page along with it's styles when clicked` - can you confirm that a request is sent to *own* server when *clicked* and what exactly is the request? It can be checked by using *developer tools* in the browser.

Comment: @LJ I am running it in my localhost so the server is the sam. The request is a Http Get with 200 OK.

Comment: The source url of `iframe` is also some resource in the same `domain`? For example, the app is hosted at say `http://localhost:80`; is the `iframe` src something like `http://localhost:80/get/thisPage`

Comment: @LJ The parent iframe's src is the same as the child source e.g. parent: `iframe src = http://localhost/index.html`, and child: `iframe src = http://localhost/index.html`.